# Manifest merger failed : Problem solving didn't work

Tags: android

Problems: There are bugs in the new version and the old version. Problems occur when updating SDK versions.

"Manifest merger failed : Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details."

There is a solution, but it gives an error as in the picture.

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
```

I think the solution should be like this, but it gives another error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because the API level (or the android version) of the device that you are trying to run the app is less than the minimum API version you specified in the gradle file.

You can find more information about API levels [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platforms).